Can't stop a coroutines, even with StopAllCoroutines(), C# Unity
By using the method setMapTypeRoadMap() i see that is not stopping the initial coroutine "StartCoroutine(UpdateMap());". and because of this the mapType is not set to type.roadMap.
i've tried everything, using creating a variable and stopping the variable that is setted up with my coroutine, i've tried to use Threads but nothing is working
// Utilized Libraries

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System;
using System.Collections;


// Map 
// This class represents an interactive map that updates every 5 seconds by taking the location from the server via phone app.

public class Map : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Questo è la API di Google per l'utilizzo della API google STATIC Map API.
    private string apiKey = "MY API";
    public enum resolution { low = 1, high = 2 }; // MAP RESOLUTION
    public resolution mapResolution = resolution.high; // HIGH RES.
    public enum type { roadmap, satellite, gybrid, terrain }; // TYPES OF MAP OF GOOGLE STATIC MAP API
    private type mapType = type.satellite; // INITIAL MAP TYPE
    private int mapWidth = 800;
    private int mapHeight = 540;



    // Definition of latitude and longitude variables.
    private float lat = 0;
    private float lon = 0;
    private int zoom = 18;

    //DEFINITION OF URL
    private string url = "";
    private Rect rect;

    
    // START
    void Start()
    {

        StartCoroutine(UpdateMap());
    }

    IEnumerator UpdateMap()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string latLast = "";
            string lonLast = "";


            //Request from the server to take the coordinates.

            using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get("MY SERVER"))
            {
                // SEND REQUEST
                yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

                if (webRequest.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
                { //Errore.
                    Debug.LogError("Error: " + webRequest.error);
                }
                else
                {
                    // GET CORDINATES
                    Coordinates data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Coordinates>(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                  //  Debug.Log("Coordinate: " + data.coordinates);

                    //EXTRACT LAT AND LON.
                    String[] parts = data.coordinates.Split(',');
                    latLast = parts[0];
                    lonLast = parts[1];

                    //Taking map measurements on Unity
                    //rect = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().rectTransform.rect;
                    //mapWidth = (int)Math.Round(rect.width);
                    //mapHeight = (int)Math.Round(rect.height);

                    //Query 
                    Debug.Log(mapType);
                    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?" +
                        "center=" + latLast + "," + lonLast +
                        "&zoom=" + zoom +
                        "&markers=color:red|" + latLast + "," + lonLast +
                        "&size=" + mapWidth + "x" + mapHeight +
                       "&scale=" + (int)resolution.high +
                        "&maptype=" + mapType +
                        "&key=" + apiKey;

                    // Get RAW IMAGE Unity.

                    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url);
                    yield return www.SendWebRequest();
                    if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
                    {//Errore
                        Debug.Log("WWW ERROR: " + www.error);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)www.downloadHandler).texture;



                    }
                }
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);  // WAIT OF 5 SEC
        }
    }


    [Serializable]
    private class Coordinates
    {
        public string coordinates;
    }

    public void setMapTypeRoadMap()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        mapType = type.roadmap;
        StartCoroutine(UpdateMap());
    }

}


I don't see a call to setMapTypeRoadMap anywhere. How are you calling it? Are you certain there is only one instance of Map?

@RetiredNinja i call setMapTypeRoadMap directly in button on Unity, the function is called properly since i checked with some debug log, but it just doesnt stop the coroutine!

How do you know it doesn't stop since you immediately start it again?

@RetiredNinja to see that the mapType is changed i need to start a coroutine again, but even tho i remove the start, it doesnt stop!

So, let's look at this from a logical perspective. If StopAllCoroutines was broken you'd have a huge bunch of people complaining about it and it is very unlikely a problem like that would get past Unity's QA folks anyway. The simple answer is that it isn't broken, it does stop the coroutine, and there's something else going on with your project that isn't giving you the desired result which is something you haven't explained. I'd focus on that. If you add debug logs before and between each of the statements in setMapTypeRoadMap do you see them?

Okay, so this is the only script i have on my project, i've tried some DebugLog() before and after, and in the console it shows the debug but right after the debug the coroutine starts and it shows the debug of what maptype is setted (the old mapType). So it looks like i cant the stop the only coroutine i have on, and also, im 100% i have only one instance of Map!

Actually there are bunch of people complaining of why StopAllCoroutines() doesnt work on their project, everyone fixed in different ways, i tried em all but it doesnt work

I can guarantee that in every case the fault was not StopAllCoroutines but in how it was being used improperly.

Store the running coroutine in a variable when you start it, and use StopCoroutine(myCoroutine) to stop it.  Since you are starting the coroutine immediately after stopping them, that is likely the reason it seems to not work.

In general be careful with what you are doing: Texture2D is not garbage collected - you have to actively Destroy it once you don't need it anymore ... right now you will be filling your RAM with unused textures. Also performance wise a RawImage is way worse than Image and since you are dealing with simple textures you should rather go for that instead
